# How to highlight input text in terminal?

Tags: python, python-3.x, input, syntax-highlighting

Is there some way to make some words in a Python 3 input get a different color than the default one of the terminal? Like this one:

```
log 'Hello World'
```

The word "log" became blue and the string "'Hello World'" became green.

Comment: Do you mean in the Python IDLE?

Comment: What do you mean by "input text"?

Comment: I cannot tell what you are asking.  Are 'blue' and 'green' something that *did* happen or something that does not happen, but you want to happen?  In other words, did you really mean 'became' (past tense) or 'should become' (desired future tense)?

Answer (score 0):

I am answering on the assumption that blue and green, for instance, are something that does not happen now but are something you would like to make happen.

If you are entering code in a system console, such as Command Prompt on Windows or Terminal on Mac and maybe some *nixes, you are unlikely to be able to get Python syntax coloring.  The console would have to be able to partially parse Python syntax.

If you are entering code in a code editor that support syntax highlighting and that can parse Python code, then you can get some coloring.  Some but not necessarily all will support user customization of colors.

IDLE divides Python code into multiple categories and offers both light and dark background schemes.  Users can start with either and change the default colors.  In your example, "log" and "'hello'" would be 'normal' and 'string' text.  In the built-in themes, normal text is either black (on white) or white (on dark blue) while strings are green.  The latter is likely why someone asked whether you are using IDLE.  You could make a theme in which normal text is a blue that contrasts with the background.